# How to update database using pandastable

Tags: pandas, tkinter, sqlite, python-3.6

i am creating a code that will take data from database and show it in pandastable . it is showing data perfectly. I edited one cell and pressed enter and downloaded data it worked perfectly. But how do i update that same cell into database also?

below are my codes for pandastable:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import Backend

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1250x650+0+0")
root.title("MAYA")
root.configure(background="black")

f = Frame(root)
f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
conn = sqlite3.connect("99_data_increment.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM crawled",conn)
pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
pt.show()
blank = ""
#Backend.insert(blank, blank, blank, blank, blank, "1", blank, blank, blank, blank, blank, blank,blank, blank, blank, blank,blank)

root.mainloop()
```

these are my codes for database:

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("99_data_increment.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crawled (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, State , XID , Project_Name , City , Main_City , Registration_Number , Promoter_Name , Rera_URL , PDF_text, Crawled_Date , Status, Names, Transaction_Date, Comments, Call_Contact_Number, Creation_Type, Builder_Website)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(State, XID, Project_Name, City, Main_City, Registration_Number, Promoter_Name, Rera_URL, PDF_text, Crawled_Date, Status, Names, Transaction_Date, Comments, Call_Contact_Number, Creation_Type, Builder_Website):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("99_data_increment.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO crawled VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(State, XID, Project_Name, City, Main_City, Registration_Number, Promoter_Name, Rera_URL, PDF_text, Crawled_Date, Status, Names, Transaction_Date, Comments, Call_Contact_Number, Creation_Type, Builder_Website))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

connect()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all data in DataFrame which can replace data using

```
df.to_sql("crawled", conn, if_exists="replace")
```

So you can add button in Tkinter which will run code with `to_sql()`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from pandastable import Table, TableModel

import sqlite3

import pandas as pd
import Backend

# --- functions ---

def save():
    df.to_sql("crawled", conn, if_exists="replace")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry("1250x650+0+0")
#root.title("MAYA")
#root.configure(background="black")

f = tk.Frame(root)
f.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

conn = sqlite3.connect("99_data_increment.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM crawled", conn)

pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
pt.show()

f = tk.Button(root, text="Save", command=save)
f.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT**

If I create own Table (using `pandatable.Table`) then I can change `handleCellEntry()` which is executed when I end editing cell - so I can see which row was changed and I could update row in database.

Something like this

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from pandastable import Table, TableModel

import sqlite3

import pandas as pd
import Backend

# --- classes ---

class MyTable(Table):

    def handleCellEntry(self, row, col):
        super().handleCellEntry(row, col)

        print('changed:', row, col, "(TODO: update database)")

        #pd.read_sql_query("UPDATE ...", conn)
        # or remeber `row` on list and `UPDATE` it later

        return

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry("1250x650+0+0")
#root.title("MAYA")
#root.configure(background="black")

f = tk.Frame(root)
f.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

conn = sqlite3.connect("99_data_increment.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM crawled", conn)

pt = MyTable(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True) # <-- MyTable
pt.show()

root.mainloop()
```